# Notifications to iOS, Android, BlackBerry from a Rails app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ios, blackberry, push-notification

I have a rails application and I would like to send notifications to users on their mobile. I only need simple text notifications, but I can't afford to write an application for any operating system.

Is there any simple way to do that? (gem, third-party services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxcar might be what you are looking for? http://boxcar.io/help/api/providers

Comment: +1 Yes, I was looking for something like this. Unfortunately it only supports iOS. Android is coming soon.

Comment: I guess another idea would be to use SMS, something like http://moonshado.com/ which is also available as an heroku plugin... Good luck either way!

Comment: Notifo seems to be a good alternative to Boxcar, but there is an announce on their blog that says "Notifo Will Be Shutting Down" :( Boxcar is so far the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Notifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) might be a solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I created a gem in order to create a central push notifications, it supports iOS and Android at the moment, but i will add more platforms.

Maybe this will help you, its a single gem that makes iOS an Android at the moment, and its fairly easy to implement

here is the link: https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup